# Problem reading a NFC Modul while showing GTK Interface

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gtk

I am programming a script in Python, which should show information with GTK Interface. The screen which is displayed should change when there is an other NFC tag at the PN532 reader.

Currently my program only does the **init** ... so it shows a Screen, prints one time "window changed" and then the program freezes.

Please help me.

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
import binascii
import socket
import signal
import sys

import Adafruit_PN532 as PN532
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject

# Pins NFC Modul
CS   = 18
MOSI = 23
MISO = 24
SCLK = 25

# Karten fuer NFC definieren
karten = {
    "hauptmenue": "hauptmenue",
    "112": "finalrs",
    "111": "v1"
}

letzter_tag = ""
startup = 1

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self, sensor):
        global letzter_tag
        self.pn532 = sensor
        letzter_tag = "hauptmenue"
        self.changewindow(part="hauptmenue")

    def changewindow(self, part):
        global startup
        if startup is not 1:
            window.destroy()
        else:
            startup = 0
        builder = Gtk.Builder()
        builder.add_from_file("/home/pi/Desktop/InterfacesRS/{0}.glade".format(part))
        window = builder.get_object("window1")
        window.show_all()
        print("window changed")

def sensorabfrage(self):
    global letzter_tag
    uid = self.pn532.read_passive_target()
    if uid is None:
        if letzter_tag is not "hauptmenue":
            letzter_tag = "hauptmenue"
            print("Kein Tag in Reichweite!")
            self.changewindow(part="hauptmenue")
        data = self.pn532.mifare_classic_read_block(4)
        if data is not None:
            action = str(int(data[2:8].decode("utf-8"), 16))
            objekt = karten.get(action)
            if objekt is not None:
                if objekt != letzter_tag:
                    letzter_tag = objekt
                    print(objekt)
                    self.changewindow(part=objekt)
    return True

def startsensortimer(self):
    GObject.timeout_add(400, self.sensorabfrage)

def main():
    pn532 = PN532.PN532(cs=CS, sclk=SCLK, mosi=MOSI, miso=MISO)
    pn532.begin()
    pn532.SAM_configuration()

    win = MainWindow(sensor=pn532)
    win.startsensortimer()
    Gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

> **Copy from comment**: I worked a bit around and got my global var into the class.
> But now I get this error: window changed Kein Tag in Reichweite!

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "sensorUI.py", line 53, in sensorabfrage
self.changewindow(part="hauptmenue") File "sensorUI.py", line 38, in changewindow 
window.destroy() 
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'window' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Why do you load `builder = Gtk.Builder()` ever `.timeout_add(400...`?

Comment: Because I wanna load a new UI (wich i created with glade) every time the NFC card changes

Comment: ***"load a new UI ... NFC card changes"***: Do you have have a different `GUI` for every `NFC -tag`? ***"the program freezes***: How do you determine this? Your `def sensorabfrage(self)` get called **onle once**.

Comment: Yeah I ahne a different GUI for every NFC tag.

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead, it's not readabel. ***`UnboundLocalError:`***: That's the drawback using `global`. Verify you have **all* your `global`variable defined as `global` or rethink your approach use `OOP` instead.